# How to use form element in Laravel 5.2 without using form facade?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-5

As I am new to laravel framework, I have a query, I am using `<form>` tag in blade template so that I can delete the data from table.

I am using this the below code of form tag to delete the data

```
 <form action="{{ route('admin.states.update',$data->state_id) }}" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" method="PUT">
```

Here I have used method as PUT, but browser is automatically considering it as GET request, I found some questions on stackoverflow where many of them said PUT & DELETE is not detected by browser.

So using Laravel Facade Form , this problem is solved

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>['admin.states.update',$data->state_id],'role'=>'form','method'=>'PUT')) !!}
```

The above code work as intended but my query is I don't want to  use Formfacade in Laravel , I want to use first type of HTML code for form opening.

Is there any other method by which I can use PUT method in HTML Form Tag without using any Form FAcade in Laravel.

Comment: look into using `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` and `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` inside the form. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-method-field

Comment: @AndrewNolan well this works for me      <form action="{{ route('admin.states.update',$data->state_id) }}" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" method="POST">
                
                {{ method_field('PUT') }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set form method to `post` and add a hidden input as following

`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">`

and also make sure to add

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

If your `ValidateCSRF` middleware is enabled.

Comment: "<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">" can also be replaced with only: "{{ crsrf_field() }}"

Comment: @Demian sorry, forgot that one :)

Comment: I used this {{ method_field('PUT') }} for <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">